# Access DigitalOcean droplet to get information about vcpus,network,memory utilization using JAVA API

Tags: java, digital-ocean

I am trying to implement Digital Ocean But i didn't get CPU utilization, memory utilization, network usage.i have been added digitalocean-api-client-1.6.jar.But it is not fully usable it has missing some classes.i followed the topic on git which referred by jeevaktm.Link as follows https://github.com/jeevatkm/digitalocean-api-java

```
package src.com.myjeeva.digitalocean;
import java.util.List;
import scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParTrieMap.Size;

import com.myjeeva.digitalocean.DigitalOcean;
import com.myjeeva.digitalocean.exception.AccessDeniedException;
import com.myjeeva.digitalocean.exception.RequestUnsuccessfulException;
import com.myjeeva.digitalocean.impl.DigitalOceanClient;
import com.myjeeva.digitalocean.pojo.Droplet;
import com.myjeeva.digitalocean.pojo.DropletSize;

import digitalocean.size.*;


public class TestDroplet {

public static void main(String args[]) throws AccessDeniedException,   ResourceNotFoundException, RequestUnsuccessfulException {

         DigitalOcean apiClient = new DigitalOceanClient("XXXX", "XXXX");

         Integer dropletId=XXXX;
        // Fetch droplet information 
         Droplet droplet1 = apiClient.getDropletInfo(dropletId);
         System.out.println("ID: " + droplet1.getId());
            System.out.println("Name: " + droplet1.getName());
            System.out.println("Status: " + droplet1.getStatus());
            System.out.println("IP Address: " + droplet1.getIpAddress());
            System.out.println("Private Ip Address: " + droplet1.getPrivateIpAddress());
            System.out.println("Image Id: " + droplet1.getImageId());
            System.out.println("Region Id: " + droplet1.getRegionId());
            System.out.println("Created Date: " + droplet1.getCreatedDate());
            System.out.println("Event Id: " + droplet1.getEventId());
            System.out.println("Active: " + droplet1.isActive());
            System.out.println("Size Id: " + droplet1.getSizeId());
            System.out.println("OS Name:" + apiClient.getImageInfo(droplet1.getImageId()).getName());
            System.out.println("Available Domain:" +apiClient.getAvailableDomains());
            System.out.println("Available Domain:" +droplet1.getSizeId());

            List<DropletSize> availableSize= apiClient.getAvailableSizes();
            for(int i=0;i<availableSize.size();i++){
            System.out.println("name :"+availableSize.get(i).getName());
            }

            DropletSize s = new DropletSize();
            //System.out.println(droplet1.getSizeId().getSize());

            //System.out.println(((Size) droplet1).getSizes());

            /* Event in progress
            long event1=droplet1.getEventId();
            int event = (int) event1;
           System.out.println("Event In process" + apiClient.getEventProgress(event));*/


            /*Availble Domains
            List<Domain> availableDomains= apiClient.getAvailableDomains();
            for(int i=0;i<availableDomains.size();i++){
            System.out.println(availableDomains.get(i).getName());
            }*/


            /* Get all Available Droplets
            List<Droplet> availableDroplets= apiClient.getAvailableDroplets();
            for(int i=0;i<availableDroplets.size();i++){
            System.out.println(availableDroplets.get(i).getName());
            }*/

            /* All Available Regions
            List<Region> availableRegions= apiClient.getAvailableRegions();
            for(int i=0;i<availableRegions.size();i++){
            System.out.println(availableRegions.get(i).getName());
            }*/
}


}
```

Comment: Can you give more details about what fails when. Error messages maybe? What code have you programmed? What Java version do you use?

Comment: That is my code.if you check the link which i have given in that project all package has been imported but i am unable to import all packages because the jar file missing some packages. so firstly i need fully completed jar file for digital ocean which will help me to get CPU utilization, memory utilization and other info like network usage and all